# Keep MySQL carriage returns when inserting in database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rtf

I have searched multiple answers from this site, google and others and I didn't find a solution for my problem

**The Problem:**

I have a SQL like this:

```
 INSERT INTO  templates(name,value)
 VALUES( 'Template 1'
 ,'{\rtf\ansi\ansicpg1252\uc1\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0 Calibri;}{\f1 Agency FB;}}       {\colortbl\red0\green0\blue0 ;\red255\green255\blue255       ;}\viewkind1\paperw12240\paperh15840\margl1425\margr1425\margt1425\margb1425\sectd\pgwsxn12240\pghsxn15840\marglsxn1425\margrsxn1425\margtsxn1425\margbsxn1425\pard\fs24\sl276\slmult1\sa180{\f1\fs24\b\ul 123}\par}'
 )
```

**But when this sql is inserted this is what i get written**

`{
tfansiansicpg1252uc1deff0deflang1033{fonttbl{f0 Calibri;}{f1 Agency FB;}}{colortbl
     ed0green0lue0 ;
     ed255green255lue255      ;}viewkind1paperw12240paperh15840margl1425margr1425margt1425margb1425sectdpgwsxn12240pghsxn    15840marglsxn1425margrsxn1425margtsxn1425margbsxn1425pardfs24sl276slmult1sa180{f1fs24ul      123}par}`

MySQL is removing \r and \

My database is in utf8_general_ci collation and utf8 charset(This will affect?)

MySQL version 5.6.17

How i do to write this text as is in the SQL to the database. Most answers want to strip it, i want to keep it.

Comment: You need to escape the backslashes.

Comment: Yes, i know that, but there is no automagic way to make mysql not to remove, escape backslashes is the only way?

Comment: Understanding how string literals work helps to understand that in this case MySQL doesn't have any control over this :)

Comment: But I've had this same insert in MS SQL sql server and this works fine. So if MSSQL has control over this, what is the reason why mysql does not? The idea is not having to use additional code and  to learn how to make this database system to make the same, or that is not posible with mysql?

Comment: Additional code? What are you using to execute the insert statement?

Comment: For executing the code only mysql workbench , to make the program vb.net

Comment: Perhaps MS SQL treats single quotes strings differently? Not sure, in any case, if you use prepared statements you will not run into this kind of issue.

Comment: And i know, i know. It's only a replace, but the question now is about why mysql doesn't work and mssql works? Where is the difference?

Comment: I tried with mysqlcommand and added parameters. This are prepared statements?

Comment: [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?103,105280,105354#msg-105354)